# Laplace transform in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to use Octave to check the solution to some differential equations using Laplace transform as part of my assignment and I'm not able to know to how to use it. I read the doc and in the example they give they use declare the t variable in the function, however in my case I don't have it specified in many cases. Here is my code for a simple example:

```
syms t s y(t) Y
dy = diff(y(t), t); 
edo = dy + 4*y(t);
edotrans = laplace(edo, t, s);
```

And this is the error I get when I run it:

```
error: Python exception: TypeError: 'Add' object is not subscriptable
    occurred at line 6 of the Python code block:
    return F[0],
error: called from
    pycall_sympy__ at line 179 column 7
    laplace at line 161 column 7
    p1 at line 4 column 10
    run at line 93 column 5
```

I'm not well versed in Octave, so is it possible that Octave doesn't support this type of operation? Or am I using it in the wrong way? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE. I found the problem to be the `diff(y(t),t)`. If for instance I do

```
syms t s y(t) Y
y = y(t);
edotrans = laplace(y, t, s);
```

it works, I get the same error if I do
syms t s y(t) Y
y = 4*y(t);
edotrans = laplace(y, t, s);
Currently the only solution I found was to apply the transform manually:

```
clc;clear;
syms t s y(t) Y
Y_s = laplace(y(t), t, s);
edo = s*Y_s - 3 + 4*Y_s - laplace(1,t,s);
edo = subs(edo, Y_s, Y);
Y = solve(edo,Y);
```

The equation is: y' +4y = 1; y(0) = 3.

Comment: octave symbolic uses the python SymPy package for implementation. Assuming it's the same issue there is a known upstream limitation in Sympy related to laplace transforms.  See https://github.com/gnu-octave/symbolic/issues/170 and https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219 . That said, i think the derivative issue itself was solved in sympy 1.10, and i can reproduce your error in symbolic package 3.1.1 with sympy 1.10.1.  left a query on the symbolic package issue page